# Python flet issue: Containers Inheriting Incorrect onclick Function Values in Loop

Tags: python, flet

I am generating flet containers through a loop and would like to assign a specific onclick function to each container, but all containers inherit the value of the last function. Below is a reproducible example where it's supposed to print the value of the button, but we can see that the value of button 'a' is 'b':

```
import flet as ft
dict = {"a": "a", "b": "b"}
def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Containers - clickable and not"
    page.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    page.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
    container = []
    images = ft.Row(expand=1, wrap=False, scroll="always")
    for key in dict:
        images.controls.append(
          ft.Container(
              content=ft.Text(key),
                margin=10,
                padding=10,
                alignment=ft.alignment.center,
                width=150,
                height=150,
                border_radius=10,
                ink=True,
                image_fit = ft.ImageFit.FILL,
                on_click=lambda e: print(key)
          )  
        )   
    page.add(images)

ft.app(target=main)
```